# pyinstaller: popen doesn't run after producing exe

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pyinstaller, popen

I compiled my python application using pyinstaller and the exe works fine, but when I run it on a different machine without python any part of the code which contains `subprocess.Popen()`doesn't run.

I read too many questions but I couldn't wrap my head around this.

My popen line:

```
try:
            process = subprocess.Popen(['python', os.path.abspath('about.py')],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                shell=True)

except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Note that the executable runs on the host machine, but on another machines it runs but fails when launching the popen.

===UPDATE====

The console shows nothing and doesn't print an exception, so I guess this is a problem with python not being found. How can I fix this?

===UPDATE2====

Following the suggestion of viilpe I used "exec(open..." but it required me to import the about.py module first; importing the module runs it on top of the main module.

Putting exec(open...) inside the try\except runs the main module and the about module alongside each other; ruining the application's GUI.

I'm using "kivy" as my GUI library.

Comment: What `print(e)` shows on fail?

Comment: @viilpe nothing at all.

Comment: maybe first see path which it runs `print( ['python', os.path.abspath('about.py')] )` and later use it directly in console to see if it can works. Maybe it need `/full/path/to/python`. Or maybe it works but problem is in `about.py`

Comment: @furas problem is python is not supposed to be installed on the machine I'm testing the exe on; I'm trying to produce the app then package it to be installed on any windows machine despite not having python in it.

Comment: but when you execute `Popen(['python' ...])` then it will search `python` in system. it will not use Python which you have in your `exe`. You should rather `import about` as any other script/module - and it would be good to have code in functions - ie in `def main()` - to run `about.main()`.

Comment: @furas I imported "about.py' but it took the place of the main module instead. When I use "exec(open('about.py').read())" with the "import" inside the try/except it runs alongside the main (on top of it actually). I use kivy for building my GUI btw

Comment: I expect some problem with `import` because normally when you have program spitted to two files then in second file you should keep code in functions (ie. `def main()`) and then when you import it then it doesn't execute it automatic but you can decide when to execute `about.main()`. If you have to run `about.py` also as separated program then you should use `if __name__ == "__main__":` for this. I also expect that in `about.py` you run new instance of kivy which makes problem with main instance of kivy - and it only means that you have to rething all your contruction.

Comment: BTW: if there is problem when you run `about.py` then first you could use `print()` inside `about.py` to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to execute `about.py` but there is no python.exe in pyinstaller bundle.
As advised [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2490) you can do it this way:

```
exec(open('about.py').read())
```

Comment: very interesting solution but i need the POPEN for my design; the about.py cannot run in the same window (or on top of the old window) like exec(open...) is doing

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of PyInstaller is to make the destination computer be able to run your script without having a standalone `python` installation. You can't run a `subprocess` on a tool which isn't (necessarily) installed.

There are various ways to run Python as a subprocess of itself natively; start by exploring the `multiprocessing` library.

If the requirement to run Python twice is not a hard one, the absolutely simplest solution is to `import about` and run the code as part of your script.  This probably requires some refactoring of the code in `about.py`.

Comment: the popen uses opencv functions for camera capture; which doesn't work with the multiprocessing library. I ditched the multiprocessing library early in development and resorted to popen.